# How I can extract string from hexadecimal python

Tags: python, string, hex

i have data which contains hexadecimal values and sting and i want to get that string value from that data using python script.
Can someone tell me how can i do that

Comment: Could you show a sample data?

Comment: bytes.fromhex(Hexadecimal).decode("ASCII")

Comment: x00@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@aSa@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@aHa@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a@a\xa2&\x02\x02\x08\xbd\x02\x01\x00\x02\x01\x000\x1a%s\x00\x08+\x06\x01\x02\x01\x01\x05\x00\x04\x8coof.zing.org'
 here is the sample

Comment: Please edit your question to include this, in a way that makes it clear what form your input data is in. It matters a great deal whether it is a string, or bytes read from a binary file, or something else.